# How to rename accounts in ethereum wallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I have 4 accounts in my ethereum wallet(using a private blockchain network) and they are named as:
1. Main Account(etherbase)
2. Account 2
3. Account 3
4. Account 4

Can anyone help me out to rename these account names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer for my question.

Just click on the account then we have an edit option in it. After selecting a particular account just click on the title, clear it and type our new name for the account.